# Heroku tracing unique request Id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-management, heroku

I've got a pretty interesting piece of log :

```
173 <190>1 2014-08-10T16:27:04.714496+00:00 d.b94e55d3-c99e-4547-865d-708591bea1ee app web.2 - - Started POST "/mandrill_inbound" for 54.184.37.188 at 2014-08-10 16:27:04 +0000
128 <45>1 2014-08-10T16:27:04.928835+00:00 d.b94e55d3-c99e-4547-865d-708591bea1ee heroku web.2 - - Process running mem=665M(130.0%)
129 <45>1 2014-08-10T16:27:04.929061+00:00 d.b94e55d3-c99e-4547-865d-708591bea1ee heroku web.2 - - Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

Summary of this is `Process running mem=665M(130.0%)`

And the related bit :

```
2014-08-10T16:27:04.745084+00:00 d.b94e55d3-c99e-4547-865d-708591bea1ee heroku router - - at=info method=POST path="/mandrill_inbound" host=www.myproject.com request_id=cfde9bb3-2cd8-4045-b3f1-235c0d4c91c3 fwd="54.184.37.188" dyno=web.2 connect=2ms service=202ms status=200 bytes=408
```

Now can I use this request id `request_id=cfde9bb3-2cd8-4045-b3f1-235c0d4c91c3` to find out which params were sent in this post request.

Or is there another way to get to the bottom of this?

If there is no way to replay what has happened here, what would be the most prudent strategy onward? Since this memory problem isn't going away on its own.

Comment: @jefflunt while it looks identical, it's not. Yes it does address part of my question, but I also ask for strategy/advice/opinion from other people how to deal with the memory issue before.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's not a lot you can do retrospectively.

The first thing you should do going forward is enable [Heroku's runtime metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-runtime-metrics), which will log resource usage for your dynos to the app's logs.

Some Heroku addons such as the [Librato](https://addons.heroku.com/librato) addon can parse these messages and use them to build graphs of memory usage over time. If you already have a Librato account, or would rather use their [pay as you go pricing](https://metrics.librato.com/pricing) you can [manually add Librato as a Heroku drain](http://support.metrics.librato.com/knowledgebase/articles/265391-heroku-native-and-custom-metrics-without-the-libra). This should give you an idea as to how your dyno's memory usage changes over time, and you can use Librato's alerting tools to let you know if the memory is maxing out frequently.

For tracking down problematic requests you could use the [oink gem](https://github.com/noahd1/oink) which puts memory/active record usage info into your logs on a per-request basis. [Here's a blog post that shows how to use oink](http://arches.io/2013/07/understand-memory-usage-on-heroku-rails-app-using-oink/) in production.